# jquery .length providing individual counts in the log, not the total

Tags: javascript, jquery, counting

The linked duplicate explains you can only use an id once, but if you read my code, each id is unique. From the linked question:

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID,
> queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in
> the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document
> with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

This however is not what my code below is doing. Before being so quick on the close trigger, please read the question or at least provide a link to an answer that actually addresses my question.

Original post:

Can someone explain why when using the code below, in the console it lists each div as "1" and a separate line item such as:
1
1
1
1
instead of logging "4"

I am trying to count the number of divs with the id that matches. It is not inside of a `.each` or anything

```
success: function (data) {
           var n = jQuery('#name_' + cid ).length;
            console.log(n)
}
```

This outputs a `<div id=name_15>` with a number that changes and is unique

Comment: when you want multiple elements access with one selector then use class and not id

Comment: The id's are unique because of the `id`. Classes arent going to be unique

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can do something like:

`var n = jQuery('.'+jQuery('#name_'+cid).attr('class')).length;`

Because when you get an element with id it just returns the length of one element with this id. but in my code, you get the class name from id (I assume class names are same), so it returns the count of elements with same class name.

Comment: ok thank you. Now that is an answer to the question and is not covered in the link above. I wish I could accept that as the answer and makes sense. I appreciate you

Comment: Yeah, that's the bad thing about here, someone can just close the question before the asker gets an answer. That's not cool and the reason I don't ask questions. Anyway, glad to help. Good luck.

Comment: @user14955679 The fact that 2 comments were made about IDs needing to be unique, and that someone closed your question for that reason shows that your question does not include enough details. Please edit your question to make it more clear _(include some example HTML)_, and I'll be glad to vote to reopen it (needs 3 votes for it to happen)

Comment: You arent reading given that the ID is unique. Each id is unique if you look at my code. It really couldnt be more clear

Comment: It could be way more clear. Anyway, glad you found a solution

Comment: Editing  the question to provide sufficient detail in the post to allow readers to reproduce the problem may have helped getting it reopened.